# Post the Area51 announcement on the SF blog

Tags: feature-request, blog

Now that Area51 has been announced on the SO blog, could you also post it on the SF blog.  In the case that people are following the SF blog and not the SO blog and understanding that that might be a pretty small set of people.  But still, how 'bout some SF love?

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that the SF blog is not meant for that sort of stuff.

The SF blog is in place to document the the Server Fault related topics that the team has to deal with.

- Hardware Upgrades
- Database Config stuff
- Load balancing
- Speed Optimizations

This is what was [posted](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/serverfaultcom/) about the serverfault blog:

> You can expect to find **blog posts there related to us documenting our own efforts of running and scaling our network of websites** — the same sort of stuff you’ve come to expect from the server category on this blog. We want to actively give back to the community by documenting everything we’re doing on the sysadmin front — both by discussing it on the blog, and asking (and answering!) relevant questions about it on Server Fault whenever possible.

Comment: Wasn't the impression that I got.

Comment: @squillman check out my edit to my answer

Comment: Still is reasonable to assume that "a blog specific to Serverfault" will have non-intersecting sets of users.